# How to make JavaScriptSerializer ignore [ScriptIgnore] tags?

Tags: c#, javascriptserializer, scriptignore

I need to make [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) ignore `[ScriptIgnore]` tags. I think I can do this with a custom [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.registerconverters.aspx). However, I am not so sure. All I need to do is ignore the attribute, and the rest can be done with the base definition. You can see the [code for `JavaScriptSerializer` here](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptSerializer@cs/1305376/JavaScriptSerializer@cs).

I am worried that implementing a custom converter, such as [this example](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ViewSample.aspx?sref=System.Web.Script.Serialization/cs/App_Code/ListItemCollectionConverter.cs) will end up not properly serializing a complex custom object graph.

Looking back to Microsoft's code for JavaScriptSerializer, on line `252-253` the code:

```
// Ignore all fields marked as [ScriptIgnore]
if (fieldInfo.IsDefined(typeof(ScriptIgnoreAttribute), true /*inherits*/)) 
 continue;
```

is the only part that I really need to bypass. I just need to have that line of code commented out. Unfortunately, that isn't really possible, so I need some method to be able to just ignore that one part of the whole process.

How can I ignore that line of code, or somehow provide a custom implementation which does not ignore `[ScriptIgnore]` attributes?

Comment: You can use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) which *ignores* `ScriptIgnore`

Comment: @L.B - I don't always want to ignore it. Moreover, Json.Net is *slow*. (source: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/27/json-net-3-5-beta-1-big-performance-improvements-compact-framework-support-and-more.aspx)

Comment: See also http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/

Comment: @L.B. - States the same thing, however, I should qualify my statement with *slow at serializing* (which is all I am after here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to mimic the JavaScriptSerializer class and provide some customization inside of the mimic'd class. Not sure I would suggest doing it, or that it is very readable. On the other hand, it works, and I love it.